# Play Framework Beginner project can't compile

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, guice

I am trying out Play Framework, but I am having trouble with the beginner project.

I use the giter8 template as described in the website:-
https://playframework.com/download

```
$ sbt new playframework/play-java-seed.g8
```

I have to use an older version of Play version as I have a current project running on the following versions:-

**Play Framework** : 2.3.10

**Scala Version** : 2.11.6

**sbt version** 0.13.12

After the application is generated. I ran

```
$ sbt clean compile
```

and I got

```
/play-by-example/build.sbt:10: error: not found: value guice
libraryDependencies += guice
                   ^
[error] Type error in expression
```

So I updated the build.sbt as below

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0"
```

and I got the following compile error:-

```
[error] /play-by-example/conf/routes:6: value index is not a member of 
object controllers.HomeController
[error] GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index
[error] /play-by-example/conf/routes:6: value index is not a member of 
object controllers.HomeController
[error] GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Has anyone encountered the same issue that can help me out?
Thanks.

Comment: Getting this same issue.  Ever find the solution?